# Facebook graph OAuthException error while trying to collect friend list of a facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect friend list of a facebook id using graph API but I am getting this Error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1,
      "fbtrace_id": "A236P7ZliSRF1NQ8ehRubqp"
   }
}
```

This is the request URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/100015894394043?fields=friends&access_token=EAABwzLixnjYBO109O4BRUj4j6KIU7ZBjnltiR2Jw82orEoz8oybX9sP4sL0mSUVjzHraGWxQPZC3OIzAjdMuZCD38TnZB3KbwbFGdjqFebQwWPWqJXBlgXrTJLcC9OHWx9MfhYA5DfDmV0X5GoXdErAhzmz2KBbBlU43S8FuyOgIaTP1MH2vzpQKWcsARlwjHFUZD

I tried requesting the URL expecting to receive the friend list, I tried my own facebook id and i got it back like that:

```
{
   "friends": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "Geroska Rosko Gay",
            "id": "1075675499"
         },
         {
            "name": "Daryan Marewan",
            "id": "61550870709628"
         },
         {
            "name": "Yadi Salam",
            "id": "61550899912209"
         },
         {
            "name": "Salam Mohamad",
            "id": "100002348820070"
         },
         {
            "name": "Hamza Omer",
            "id": "100003376750888"
         },
         {
            "name": "Mariwan Hawrame",
            "id": "100004205682390"
         },
         {
            "name": "Renas Sayfadin",
            "id": "100013924509986"
         },
         {
            "name": "Pana",
            "id": "100026664979141"
         },
         {
            "name": "Harry Reynolds",
            "id": "100027929721150"
         },
         {
            "name": "Hastyar Jabar",
            "id": "100028435356341"
         },
         {
            "name": "Tunay Sunay",
            "id": "100030414763579"
         },
         {
            "name": "Darya Esmael",
            "id": "100033144504770"
         },
         {
            "name": "Muhamad Ardallan",
            "id": "100033509192204"
         },
         {
            "name": "Bafraw Husen",
            "id": "100050735812994"
         },
         {
            "name": "Nashwan B Halabjay",
            "id": "100058104381576"
         },
         {
            "name": "Zhyar Ali",
            "id": "100067070786456"
         },
         {
            "name": "Edd Ramz",
            "id": "100070211135569"
         },
         {
            "name": "A HM AD",
            "id": "100071109376990"
         },
         {
            "name": "Tishky Hataw",
            "id": "100072242057377"
         },
         {
            "name": "Zhuan Salam",
            "id": "100076848215428"
         },
         {
            "name": "\u06a9\u06c6\u06af\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u062e\u0632\u0646 \u0626\u0627\u0631\u0627\u0645",
            "id": "100078520594560"
         },
         {
            "name": "Hama Gian",
            "id": "100081550290073"
         },
         {
            "name": "Brwa Akbar",
            "id": "100081937148806"
         },
         {
            "name": "Dakota Davis",
            "id": "100083292155207"
         },
         {
            "name": "Muhamad Halabjay",
            "id": "100083759749316"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUk5sc1VVRVluenRlc1lxOGpGYlFMNDRFMWpRdzMyRHl4dmU5ZAmtJYkYweHBWZAVJIZATJOTDVRNEJiVVpWSEE2MWQZD",
            "after": "QVFIUmRkYWhXZAUNPQVdoYkRvVGR1bFJfdmtHTkt4SVVSNlFoU3dmUFRPMTdSbFZAkUVRIQWViVDFPVFJ3UlVrRTRlSUktSXlnU0Rqdi1qeGYtS0tfeTBlQ1RR"
         },
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/100092254886657/friends?access_token=EAABwzLixnjYBO109O4BRUj4j6KIU7ZBjnltiR2Jw82orEoz8oybX9sP4sL0mSUVjzHraGWxQPZC3OIzAjdMuZCD38TnZB3KbwbFGdjqFebQwWPWqJXBlgXrTJLcC9OHWx9MfhYA5DfDmV0X5GoXdErAhzmz2KBbBlU43S8FuyOgIaTP1MH2vzpQKWcsARlwjHFUZD&pretty=1&limit=25&after=QVFIUmRkYWhXZAUNPQVdoYkRvVGR1bFJfdmtHTkt4SVVSNlFoU3dmUFRPMTdSbFZAkUVRIQWViVDFPVFJ3UlVrRTRlSUktSXlnU0Rqdi1qeGYtS0tfeTBlQ1RR"
      },
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 28
      }
   },
   "id": "100092254886657"
}
```